# Insert and then get value from a select

Tags: c#, sql

Help I am new to SQL query I have 3 tables the `tbl_STUDENT` , `tbl_SESSION` and `tbl_STUDENTSESSION` I want to pass the `total_session` value from `tbl_SESSION` to `tbl_STUDENTSESSION` table.
im getting incorrect syntax near 'select' Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_STUDENTSESSION(Student_ID, Session_ID, Total_Session) 
VALUES (6000, 4000, Select Total_Session from tbl_SESSION where Session_ID = 4000);
```

Comment: any error message?

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: incorrect syntax near 'select'

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use

```
INSERT INTO tbl_STUDENTSESSION(Student_ID,Session_ID,Total_Session)  Select 6000,4000, Total_Session from tbl_SESSION where Session_ID=4000
```